# Adding inApp browser inside a Div

Tags: html, cordova, iframe, inappbrowser, childbrowser

Am working in HTML5 PhoneGap Application.
I want embedded a website in to my Application. We can Use InApp Browser/ChildBrowser for this. But normally its loading as another window. 
I want to add the InApp `Browser/ChildBrowser` **inside a Div element**

like the image given;

[image]

Here Header and Footer should be visible and which is the part of the App. Inside the Dive element i want to open the Website. Is there any solution ?

Or Can we use iframe for this?

I want to Develop the app for `iPad`.

Comment: hi @ullas-mohan-v have you found the answer? I need this too, thank you

Comment: @danisupr4 : Finally i used "iframe" for my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V,
as far as i know, it is not possible to use the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) with the attribute `inline`.

When i did this the last time, i did it like you supposed to do this -> with an iFrame. You can use the iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="../../../index.htm" width="90%" height="400" name="SELFHTML_in_a_box">
  <p>Sorry, but your browser can't display iframes <a href="../../../index.htm">SELFHTML</a></p>
</iframe>
```

But i would relinquish on the `<p>` tag. So just only use the iFrame.

So i hope, this helped you. If not, let me know. Then i'm going to explained it with more details!

Comment: where is "window.open()" syntax ?

Comment: For what do u need window.open when the iframe is displayed inline? You just use it, when you want to open the link in a new window (inappbrowser)